# Java/Javascript -> Multiple users working on same sql-datasource that has to be consistent in frontend

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, sql

I'm working on an web application that presents data from an SQL-Table in a frontend.

**UPDATE:**

Database is PostgreSQL 9.4

My Application is a Maven Web-Application using java servlets for logic and jsp pages for presentation.

There are multiple users working on the same data (same sql table as data source)

How can I manage to have the same data available to all users at all times?

Example:

- User A & B view the html table with data (user sql table)
- User A does changes to the data like adding a new user into the sql table (via a button an sql inset statement is triggered)
- User B should be able to see the changes made to that table

As of right now, only when user B refreshes the page, the data is pulled again from the sql table & he is able to see changes that another user made.

Problem is my current state is:

- User A & B view the html table with all users
- User A deletes user C
- User A (that doenst yet see that user C has been deleted from the sql table) wants to change an attribute of user C (like change his name)
- he then does the namechange but the sql udate query (that is being triggered by a button) will fail since user C has been deleted from the sql table by user A

Is there any method of displaying multiple users the same data that is always up to date so both users can work on the exact same data at all times??

Comment: What kind of server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a WebSocket connection to keep your users up to date. Every call to your API will have to push the relevant changes to all affected users. Depending on your API design this might not be hard to implement at all.

If you simply want to keep consistency, implement some kind of record locking. Add a new column to your table e.g. `last_updated` and let any `UPDATE` or `DELETE` operations through your API fail until the `last_updated` column is consistent with what your user sends to the server. This will ensure that only a user that is in possession of the correct current record may issue `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements against it.

Some [further reading](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/HomeWebsocket/WebsocketHome.html) on WebSockets in Java

Comment: that would work, I get that. But the user still has to refresh his view on the data to see changes made by others. I dont know how this is done "the right way" but should the users view on the data update if the database table has been modified?

Comment: @Alkahna Using a WebSocket connection to your users browsers would allow you to push changes to the currently displayed tables.

Comment: so I need a java class (I have java classes/servlets for logic and jsp pages to display the frontend) that checks if the data a user is looking at is the same as the one in the sql table right?

Comment: @Alkahna simply send a push notification to all clients when the data is changed by any one of them. e.g. in your `POST` request handler.

Comment: I never worked with push notifications before, how could I manage this & a javaclass still needs to check database state and compare this to the state a specific user is looking at in that moment. I dont really know how to realize this in code

Comment: I've added a link to a page describing "Building Web Applications with WebSocket, JavaScript and HTML5"